# How to hide LiveTile count but show LockScreen notification count?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, lockscreen, live-tile

As we all know that the lock screen notification count is directly picked from the live tile count in WindowsPhone8. However i am using a custom tile design for my app and don't want the primary live tile count to show but still want the lock screen notification count to work. Is there any way i can achieve both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed that if the primary tile is not pinned on the homescreen and you set the count, it is displayed on the lockscreens. So my idea, which I have not tested, is to make the app create a secondary tile on the homescreen (instead of making the user to pin the app) with your custom design and set the count for the primary tile. If this does not work, I think nothing will.

Comment: Yes i think that's the only way out to this problem.. Thanks a lot!!